# Permissions access changend on the server by it self

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

i hosted a wordpress web site and everything works fine , but the permissions access of the wordpress (index, settings) keep changing from 755 to 000 and causing 500 error , any one have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Give permission to entire project 755 to the directory only and 644 to the files only.